# /t aka Tab in PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

I'm generating a string of text from my php via either Echo or print_r. I'm trying to make it fit into google spreadsheet and Excel column accordingly. eg

```
HEllo World test

Hello on First Column
World on Second Column
test on third Column
```

In Windows form, i can easily add a /t and it will paste into excel and spreadsheet accordingly but in php it doesnt.

I have tried /t and ;&nbsp and commas

Any Idea how i can get it to paste into columns accordingly?

Comment: In the very least, you'll need to use `\t`, not `/t`

Comment: @zdhickman OMG Thank you. Such a silly mistake i'm making over here!

Comment: I went ahead and threw it up as an answer. I assumed there was going to be more to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP recognizes a tab with `\t`, not `/t`!